# Can i register a new website domain with firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'm working on new mobile app project and we are trying to register a new website domain for the product. But it requires a server IP address. My question is there a way to use firebase services to provide a server IP address ?

Comment: AFAIK, firebase will not provide you that.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not provide DNS services.  Firebase Hosting will give let you attach your existing domain name to its web hosting service, but it will not give you a dedicated static IP address.